# Looping & Adding Values

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to run a loop that looks for a value in a column and if it is found then another value is entered in the cell to the right of it.

```
m = 2
h = 1
    Cells(m, 23).Select
Do
    Cells(m, 23).Select
    If ActiveCells <> " " Then

        Cells(m, 24) = "Test"

    End If

If InStr(Cells(m, 24).Text, "-") Then
    h = h + 1
End If

m = m + 1
```

What I am finding is the script runs and does not seem to identify when the cell contains the word "Region". It is just skipping over as if the cell is empty.

Still pretty new to VBA's so this may or may not be an easy fix.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Dim lr As Long
Dim m As Long: m = 2
Dim h As Long: h = 1

'Properly reference objects
With Sheets("YourActualSheetName")
    'To add better control, identify boundaries of your loop,
    'so find the last row that contain data.
    lr = .Columns(23).Find(What:="*", _
                           After:=.Cells(1, 23), _
                           SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    Do
        'You can use one liner If's for some cases like this one
        If .Cells(m, 23) = "Region" Then .Cells(m, 24) = "Type"
        If InStr(.Cells(m, 24), "-") <> 0 Then h = h + 1
        m = m + 1
    Loop Until m > lr
End With
```

**Edit1:** <sup>As stated in the comments</sup>

```
Dim m As Long: m = 2
Dim h As Long: h = 1

With Sheets("YourActualSheetName")
    Do
        If .Cells(m, 23) = "Region" Then .Cells(m, 24) = "Type"
        If InStr(.Cells(m, 24), "-") <> 0 Then h = h + 1
        m = m + 1
    Loop Until h = 9
End With
```

Comment: It looks like the loop will happen until m>lr but I just need it to run until h=9. That way it cuts back the number of times it actually loops. I don't want to run the script if it's unnecessary. Thank you!

Comment: @JamesMyungHunPak If that is the case, you do not need the `lr`. You didn't mention that in your question though. Fixed.

Comment: awesome. had to tweak the code a little b/c i made some errors in the original post so it kept looping with no end. but that was fixed. thank you for your help!!!